# How to organize assets?

Tags: angular, dart

I wrote a component that contains an image. The file structure looks like: [image]

My question is, it is right choise to put assets folder into web folder?
**UPDATE**

I tried as follow:

```
import 'package:angular2/core.dart';
import 'package:angular2_components/angular2_components.dart';
import 'package:wp_login/models/Login.dart';
import 'package:wp_login/assets/scale.svg';

@Component(
    selector: 'start-app',
    directives: const[MaterialInputComponent],
    styleUrls: const ['login_component.css'],
    templateUrl: 'login_component.html')
class AppComponent {

  String scaleImg = 'scale.svg';
  Login login;


  onSubmit() {
    print('Submit');
  }

}
```

And the file structure:
[image]

But it does not work at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suggest to put everything into `lib`, actually `lib/asset`, if it's reused in several places, or `lib/login_component`, together with the component files if they belong together.

Referencing files in `web` from files in `lib/**` is bad practice.

I also suggest not putting anything into `web` that doesn't need to be there.
References to `lib` work the same from everywhere (from `web`, `lib`, `test`, ..., but references to `web` only work from within `web`.

Refer to files in `lib` always using

```
packages/my_package/file_or_dir.xxx
```

(note the missing `lib`)

From files within `lib` also relative paths like are fine

```
../file_or_dir.xxx
```

or just

```
file_or_dir.xxx
```

Comment: So you want to stick with `scale.png` in `web` even when I explained that it's not a good idea and that imports of files in `web` from files in `lib` don't work well?

Comment: I put now `scale.png` into `lib/assets` folder and do not know how to reference in the component.

Comment: I see. The screenshot doesn't reflect that. I guess you need `String scaleImg = 'packages/my_package/assets/scale.svg';` or `String scaleImg = '../packages/my_package/assets/scale.svg';` You can try with `String scaleImg = 'assets/scale.svg';` but I'm not sure if this works for assets.

Comment: The first one it works like a charm. By the way, how do to know about `packages/...` file system. You are the master of dart lang.

Comment: In recent versions `pub get` and `pub upgrade` created such folders everywhere and they were kinda retained with `pub build` so the same paths work after Dart was built to JS. In the recent versions these directories are not created anymore by default but most tools can now use the generated `.packages` file to emulate this behavior (except for example SASS - not yet). So you can just assume the `packages` directory is always available in Dart

Comment: Thanks you to much for helping.

Comment: I really enjoy dart, no packages hell anymore. Hopefully the community will decide for dart too.

Comment: Sure. There is so much exiting stuff in the pipeline.